# Why is there activity on our FTP server while Cloudberry FTP backup says job is finished?

Tags: cloudberry

Here is the setup

1. We are testing Cloudberry for backing up files to a remote FTP server
2. As a test we are backing up files on a desktop, using Cloudberry FTP to a FTP server (FileZilla server) located on the same desktop. The FileZilla Server in turns is accessing a Synology NAS located on the same network.
3. The job is set to run every 24 hours
4. According the Cloudberry interface, it was last run at midnight and latested 1h 31min
5. There are no running jobs showing in Cloudberry interface
6. HOWEVER, it is 9AM , FileZilla server is still showing files upload.  Filezilla has a counter to keep track on the number connection. The count is currently at 1.2million, but thereare only ~ 70,000 file being backed up.
7. I deleted the job and created a new one with the same result

So what is going on?

Alex

Comment: Also, if CloudBerry Support Staff are monitoring this, we are an MSP and doing this to test if we could offer this to our clients, so far, I wouldn't...

Comment: Are you sure all this still coming from Cloud backup?

Comment: "Are you sure all this still coming from Cloud backup?"
As soon as I stopped the "CloudBerry Backup Service", the traffic on the FTP server stopped. So yes, I am sure that it is coming from CloudBerry

Comment: As an update to point 6 of my original question, today the FTP server has recorded 5 millions connection. This seems excessive, given there are only 70K files to backup and the job is set to run once a week only.


Also I noticed from the FTP logs that CloudBerry is uploading files that are NOT included in the CloudBerry backup selection -anymore-. It feels as if there is a hidden (old) job that is still running in the background.

Comment: Edit - Sorry did not know different between  a comment and an anwer.

Comment: I got a refund from Cloudberry because it never worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

Found the root cause of this issue.

By looking through the logs in %programdata%\CloudBerryLab\CloudBerry Backup\Logs, I found that a Consistency job was running every hour...

No matter how many times I checked the Backup Job definition, this setting was never shown as it is only displayed in the Welcome tab, not the Backup Plans tab...

Changed the Consistency job to running weekly.

Hope this will help somebody else

Note: Disappointed with the lack of Support from CloudBerry given that Stackoverflow is officially their Support page as per  http://www.cloudberrylab.com/support.aspx?page=support